# Yii2: Use Html::tag() with HTML content for tooltip Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hint: Formating as raw won't fix my problem - See attachement respectively picture:
[image]

The following code will implement tooltip using attribute `title` of method `tag()`.

Unfortunately, there is no possibility rendering HTML-tags inside the title. Any ideas(links are welcome) how to implement tooltip handling my intention to render HTML tags? Is there any other option implementing tooltip-box outside attribute
`title`, so that I am able to render HTML-tags

```
    [
        'attribute' => $dummy,
        'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Charakterisierung'),
        'format' => 'raw',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'value' => function($model) {
            if (!(empty($model->person->personentypDominant->typ_name))) {
                $tag = Html::tag('span', 'Tooltip-Touch Me!', [
                            // html-tags won't be rendered in title
                            'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung],
                            'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                            'data-placement' => 'left',
                            'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:1px solid red;'
                ]);
                return $tag . "<br>" . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_im_team_1 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_bei_stress_3 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_am_arbeitsplatz_4;
            }
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**`Html::tag()`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#generating-tags) takes 3 parameters like below

```
<?= Html::tag($name, $content = '', $options = []) ?>
```

Then if you look into the documentation for the bootstrap [**`Tooltip`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-options) options there is an option named `HTML`

> Insert HTML into the tooltip. If false, jQuery's text method will be
>   used to insert content into the DOM. Use text if you're worried about
>   XSS attacks.

Which has the default value as `false` and you have to set it manually to `true`.

So apparently, you have 3 problems

- You are closing the options `]` on the line `'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung ],`
- There isn't any attribute with the name `vAlign` for [**`yii\grid\DataColumn`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html) untill unless you are using `kartik\grid\DataColumn` then it's ok.
- You are not initializing tooltip with the option `HTML` true.

First of all, add the following to the top of your view or inside the layout file if want to apply these setting allover

```
$js = <<<SCRIPT
/* To initialize BS3 tooltips set this below */
$(function () { 
   $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
        html:true
    });
});
SCRIPT;
// Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript
$this->registerJs ( $js );
```

Change your code for `GridView` to the following, i assume that `$model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung ,` has the `HTML` that you are trying to render

```
[
    'attribute' => $dummy ,
    'label' => Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Charakterisierung' ) ,
    'format' => 'raw' ,
    'value' => function($model) {
        if ( !(empty ( $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_name )) ) {
            $tag = Html::tag ( 'span' , 'Tooltip-Touch Me!' , [
                   // html-tags won't be rendered in title
                   'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung ,
                   'data-placement' => 'left' ,
                   'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'
                   'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:1px solid red;'
            ] );
            return $tag . "<br>" . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_im_team_1 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_bei_stress_3 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_am_arbeitsplatz_4;
        }
    }
];
```

---

## `EDIT`

You need to use the column `format` as `raw` when using the gridview otherwise the tooltip won't render.

```
"format"=>"raw"
```

---

## `Edit 2`

Make Sure you are not Using `AdminLTE` theme with `jquery UI` as they have a conflict SEE [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/210).

The causes of conflict on the `jquery UI` tooltip and the `bootstrap` tooltip are `jQuery UI` tooltip overwrite the `Bootstrap` tooltip maybe they use the same namespace and function name.

Add the following code in your javascript (solution from [**`here`**](https://seegatesite.com/problem-solve-tooltip-adminlte-bootstrap-framework-conflict-with-jquery-ui/))

```
var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
$.fn.bstooltip = bootstrapTooltip;
$('element').bstooltip();
var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
$.fn.bstooltip = bootstrapTooltip;
$('element').bstooltip();
```

## `Demo`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bootstrapTooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
  $.fn.bstooltip = bootstrapTooltip;
  $('#mybtn').bstooltip();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin:100px;">
  <button id="mybtn" title="my tooltip showing now">hover me</button>
</div>
```

The point that needs attention is that we must put the `jqueryui.js` before `bootstrap.js`, so you have to rearrange your `.js` files in the `$js` array inside the `AppAsset` file you are using to load all the scripts.

Comment: Thx a lot for this. Works pretty fine!

Comment: :) happy to help @tklustig

Comment: There is any attribute with the name vAlign for kartik\grid\DataColumn. I'm using GridView of kartik!

Comment: ahh , wasnt mentioned so i thought your are using default gridview , thats y mentioned `yii\grid\DataColumn` will update in the answer too

Comment: Formating as raw won't fix my problem(see Hint above)

Comment: tooltip will be rendered, independent of using raw or html. html-tags won't be rendered in both cases

Comment: nopes that is incorrect, that using none of the above will show the tooltip, until unless you use `raw` you wont be able to render the tooltip, inside the gridview @tklustig ,

Comment: So I assume, that some CSS-rule of AdminLTE prevents rendering html-tags! I have no idea, of course,which one this colud be. Will U be able to render html-tags using AdminLTE,too??

Comment: Well, `AdminLTE` already uses `bootstrap 3.x`  i do not think that it would be the reason as I have used it in the previous project and never faced this problem, i am also a bit confused why would it not work at your end @tklustig can you try a hardcoded `html` string to render inside the `title` tag with `<br>` and `<ul>` tags although the `ul` tags are already rendered but for the sake of troubleshooting just try rendring the hardcoded html does it work.

Comment: No usnig code like this:   'title' => '<br><ul><li>Hallo</ul></li>', won't render html-tags P.S.: Changing layoutfile will render html-tags, but I need AdminLTE!

Comment: kindly mark this answer as correct again @tklustig hope you have no concerns over it

Comment: Solved! After having removed app.min.js and copied adminlte.js into js folder and integrated this js-file in my asset-class, html-tags finally will be rendered! Thx for ur efforts helping me! Gave u reputation twice, in both threads! Greetings to Agypt!

Comment: i appreciate that :) @tklustig Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Please note that now bootstrap 3.4.1 and 4.3.1 has a [sanitizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer) that block most of HTML tags by default.

If your tooltip (or popover) data-content contain one or more HTML tags not listed in the default whitelist, you need to add them manually:

```
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList

// To allow table elements
myDefaultWhiteList.table = []

// To allow td elements and data-option attributes on td elements
myDefaultWhiteList.td = ['data-option']

// You can push your custom regex to validate your attributes.
// Be careful about your regular expressions being too lax
var myCustomRegex = /^data-my-app-[\w-]+/
myDefaultWhiteList['*'].push(myCustomRegex)

// initialize your tooltip
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        // set your custom whitelist
        whiteList: myDefaultWhiteList
    });
});
```